# What does "the day has turned over" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> p1: What time is it?
> p2: **The day has turned over**. It is monday 02:50am,
> You've been unconcious for nearly 5 hours.
> p1: Otta got me didn't he?
> p2: He struck you over the head with a wok.

What does "the day has turned over" mean?

Comment: It is not a usual expression. In any case, if you think of the 12 hours from midnight to noon and the 12 hours from noon to midnight, as lying on opposite sides of a flat sheet of paper, it's pretty clear that midnight is past. A new days begins. In fact, P2: says it's 2:50 am.

Comment: What do you think it means?  I've never heard this expression before, but I think the context makes it very clear!

Comment: This should be obvious by looking at the 02:50am and understanding what would have changed from 5 hours ago to now. However, who says "02:50am" in speech? :)

Answer (score 1):

Old fashioned mechanical 'digital' clocks used to 'roll over' or 'turn over'. Like a Rolodex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'The day has turned over' means that the day has ended.

I believe this is from the thought that the sun and moon spin around the Earth, meaning 'the day has turned over' meaning that the sun / moon has taken a turn.

Comment: I think it is more likely to mean that the indicated time has passed from 23:59:59 to 00:00:00.